# cygssp-0.dll error git/cygwin

Tags: windows, git, dll, cygwin, registry

I have a project that I am building using cygwin as an env. This weekend, I tried to do a standard git pull, one that has worked hundreds of times before, and I get this message.

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
/usr/bin/ssh.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygssp-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm a bit confused since this has never happened before. I googled "cygssp-0.dll" and found that it is some .dll file, specifically I looked [here](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/windows-software-developer/third-party-application/cygssp-0-dll/).

I tried the first option, and got to this step

```
enter "regsvr32 /u cygssp-0.dll" in the command line
```

and I got the message

```
The module "cygssp-0.dll" failed to load. 

Make sure the binary is stored at the specific path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files. 

The specific module could not be found.
```

At this point, I am thoroughly confused, and not all too keen to start reinstalling windows just yet. I've tried re installing cygwin.. does anybody have any ideas on what to do?

EDIT : I have already attempted to run setup-x86_64.exe several times, in an attempt to re-install something from the cygwin side.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your antivirus off of silent mode or turn off heuristics. It's just deleting the file without telling you. libssp is getting deleted because it's a security library that does things to the call stack that antivirus programs don't like. (Specifically, it adds canaries, random values inserted into the stack that are meant to guard against some buffer overflow attacks. However, an antivirus that isn't coded to handle stack canary insertion will see it as a buffer overflow attack itself.)

Comment: Still a bit confused.. what in this case is "it"? My antivirus has deleted a security library?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today while trying to do push via Cygwin's git via ssh.

The solution is to reinstall or update Cygwin, as missing library will be redownloaded and put in proper place. Be sure that your antivirus software isn't removing it again, so disable everything that might delete it, and/or whitelist `cygssp-0.dll` location. As of today they're located under:

- `cygwin_root\bin\cygssp-0.dll`
- `cygwin_root\usr\i686-pc-cygwin\sys-root\usr\bin\cygssp-0.dll`

(second path only for 64 bit distribution of Cygwin)